# angularjs strings & string trees

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to find a solution to do this.

I want to use a string like this for a tag-like setup

toys/cars/red

and then I want ng-repeat to make this.

toys
toys/cars
toys/cars/red

And if one of these are clicked a filter will look through my entities if they contain the clicked string.

So the problem I'm having is, how can I make this toys/cars/red into

toys
toys/cars
toys/cars/red

before ng-repeat shows the values.

then only part I have solved is to remove all duplicate strings before ng-repeat shows them.

**EDIT**

```
var uniqueTypes = [];
for(i = 0; i< firstPointFiveFilter.length; i++){    
    if(uniqueTypes.indexOf(firstPointFiveFilter[i].category) === -1){
        uniqueTypes.push(firstPointFiveFilter[i].category);        

            var str = uniqueTypes + '';
            arr = str.split('/'),
            e = '';
            var arr2 = [];

            arr.forEach(function (item) {
            e += item + '/';
            arr2.push(e);
            });

            console.log(arr2);




    }        
}
```

the different strings are like this without the code from @dark4p
['toys/cars/red', 'toys/cars/blue']

**EDIT 2**

Thanks for your answers @dark4p, the only thing missing now is this.

if I have `['toys/cars/red', 'toys/cars/blue']`
Then it should not be

toys
toys/cars
toys/cars/red

toys
toys/cars
toys/cars/blue

it should look like this

toys
toys/cars
toys/cars/red
toys/cars/blue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the string before ng-repeat like this:

```
var str = 'toys/cars/red',
    arr = str.split('/'),
    e = '';
    arr2 = [];

arr.forEach(function (item) {
    e += item;
    arr2.push(e);
    e += '/';
});

console.log(arr2);
```

Hope this helps

---

EDIT:

If you have multiple strings like so:

```
function pathSplitter(arr) {
  var e = '',
      arr2 = [];

  if (!arr.length) {
     return 'Please make sure you pass an array in this function.';
  }

  arr.forEach(function (item) {
     e += item;
     arr2.push(e);
     e += '/';
  });

  return arr2;  
}

var str = 'chair/fabric/black,chair/fabric/grey',
    arr = str.split(',');

arr.forEach(function (item) {
  var subItemArr = item.split('/');

  // DO STUFF OR JUST PRINT IT
  console.log(pathSplitter(subItemArr));
});
```

---

EDIT 3:

Working with Stackoverflow editor is pain so I created a jsbin - http://jsbin.com/hawoqinufi/edit?html,js,output

---

EDIT 4:

How about this: http://jsbin.com/zozesodiqa/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now I'm getting close but not all the way though, here is what I get when I have one piece of content with chair/fabric/black and one with chair/fabric/grey
"chair/", "chair/fabric/", "chair/fabric/black,chair/", "chair/fabric/black,chair/fabric/", "chair/fabric/black,chair/fabric/grey/"

Comment: That can't be right.. do you have multiple paths in `str`? Can you please paste the `str` variable?

Comment: Awesome, now the only problem is I only get one of these results shown in the ng-repeat
 ["chair", "chair/fabric", "chair/fabric/black"]
["chair", "chair/fabric", "chair/fabric/grey"]

But it should be 
`chair
chair/fabric<br>
chair/fabric/black<br>
chair/fabric/grey`

Comment: Thanks alot, I added a new edit, would it require much change to achieve that?

Comment: dark4p for president! :)